# Java 8 Comparator keyExtractor

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

In Java 8 Comparator, we can create a comparator as follows.

```
Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor);
```

Currently I have a class as follows

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    Department dept;
}

class Department {
    String departmentName;
}
```

Now, if I want to create a comparator for Employee class which sorts the records based on the department name, how can I write my key extractor?

Tried the below code, but did not work.

```
Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDept::getDepartmentName);
```

Comment: `Comparator.comparing((Employee e) -> e.getDept().getDepartmentName())`

Comment: That is not how method references work.  You need to write an explicit lambda: `Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getDept().getDepartmentName())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is method references are not objects and don't have members to access. So you can't do this:

```
Employee::getDept.getDepartmentName
```

Moreover, method references are not classes, so you can't get another method reference from them. So this also fails.

```
Employee::getDept::getDepartmentName
```

Finally, the only option that is left with us is this.

```
e -> e.getDept().getDepartmentName()
```

Try this out,

```
Employee empOne = new Employee("Mark", new Department("Accounts"));
Employee empTwo = new Employee("Melissa", new Department("Sales"));
List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(empOne, empTwo);
employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getDept().getDepartmentName()));
employees.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: How to add null check for this. If any department object is null it will throw npe.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [function that extracts a sort key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-)

I.e.

```
Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDept,Comparator.comparing(Department::departmentName));
```

Comment: yes this is actual solution, full sort code would look as:

...stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDept,Comparator.comparing(Department::departmentName)));